# doing online surveys with spring mvc and limesurvey

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, survey, surveymonkey, limesurvey

hi i'm working in a spring mvc project and i need to add a survey option, the requeriment is sending a link inside a email to a survey or i dont know if you can send the questions inside the email, i will probably lean for the firts option, i'm thinking of using limesurvey or any other open source survey tool who can be integrated with my spring mvc web application.

since i have not worked with a survey tool before, how acctually limesurvey works i asume that this is how it works:

1) you install limesurvey in your server
2) you create the survey with limesurvey UI after it was succesfully installed in your server
3) that survey that i just create give me somekind of URL

if this assumptions are correct,

QUESTIONS: 
1) how can i get that url in my spring mvc application so i could send it in a email, since they are to different applications, does lime survey save that url in data base where i could connect with my spring mvc application and get it?

2) the same thing goes with the results can i get access with my spring mvc application to the results since i need that info to create reports,

3) can i create limesurvey surveys from my spring mvc application, if limesurveys create the surveys in a data base can i crete them from and UI in spring and save them in the limesurvey database

4) is there a way to configure the valid period time of a survey, since i dont want that a user can access the survey for long periods of times like 1 hour doing the survey, or being able to access the survey from the link for a entire week, since this can be a problem to my server capacity

Answer (score -1):

1. Url : if unique link for each user is needed : https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API#get_participant_properties . Else a survey link it's allways the same example.org/surveyid.html for example.

   2. https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API#export_statistics
   3. https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API#add_survey and/or https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API#import_survey etc ...
   4. Start and expiry date-time : https://manual.limesurvey.org/Survey_settings#Publication_.26_access_control

Then : I think LS are able to be integrated in your MVC. ANd remind : you can too use Extra plugin use LS core system with newDirectRequest event : https://manual.limesurvey.org/NewDirectRequest Return some json for your MVC if it's easiest for you.

Denis

Comment: thnkas for the info friend,  but regarding my firts question, that link `example.org/surveyid.html` is stored in the database? since i want to send that link inside a email using my spring mvc web application, is there a way to get that link from a database? because if i `create a new` survey and want to keep the old survey i dont want to have my code hardcoded to that specific link, it would be great if could create a survey in limesurvey and then in my spring mvc web application have a method that return me those urls

Comment: surveyid is stored in the database. Link can be constructed with only surveyid .... Why do you want to have it in DB ? You already have all to do it yourself .... Surveyid can not be updated it's the identifier of the survey. Use a redirect can be easily done ... with any other url.